# Receiving "incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8" error on simple Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake, rails-migrations

I have a trivial Rails migration that is failing when I run `rake db:migrate`. This is in a development environment using SQLite3. This is the migration:

```
class RemoveMobileUserIdFromDevices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_column :devices, :mobile_user_id
  end

  def down
    add_column :devices, :mobile_user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

I am experiencing the following error when running `rake db:migrate`:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  RemoveMobileUserIdFromDevices: migrating ==================================
-- remove_column(:devices, :mobile_user_id)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:516:in `*'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:516:in `block in copy_table_contents'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/result.rb:20:in `block in each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/result.rb:20:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/result.rb:20:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:514:in `copy_table_contents'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:478:in `copy_table'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:455:in `move_table'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:448:in `block in alter_table'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:447:in `alter_table'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:387:in `block in remove_column'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:386:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:386:in `remove_column'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:447:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:422:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:422:in `say_with_time'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:442:in `method_missing'
/Users/username/[removed]/[removed]/db/migrate/20120127204256_remove_mobile_user_id_from_devices.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:394:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:394:in `block in migrate'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `with_connection'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:375:in `migrate'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:507:in `migrate'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:687:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `call'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:686:in `block in migrate'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:671:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:671:in `migrate'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:549:in `up'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:530:in `migrate'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:161:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I'm not sure what the issue could be, as I have previous migrations with similar commands that have executed without issue. So far, I have tried typing the migration file by hand in TextMate (under the presumption that the actual file may have had a bad character encoding). I have also deleted the migration and recreated it via `rails g migration RemoveMobileUserIdFromDevices mobile_user_id:integer` but have seen no change.

Comment: What else is in your `devices` table? The "block in copy_table_contents" in the stack trace is suspicious.

Comment: Quite a bit... including some binary columns which I suspect were causing the issue. I removed all of my table entries and then was able to complete the migration. Do you have any idea why the binary columns would be causing the issue? Binary is binary, right? I would think that character encodings would be completely separate of this. It would only come into play within the actual rails app when manipulating the binary data.

Comment: `t.binary` might end up being a plain string with SQLite.

Comment: SQLite apparently uses the blob datatype for rails binary columns. Couldn't find much information other than possible hints of SQLite possibly not having true binary support (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/252531-storing-binary-data-in-sqlite/). Lesson learned: binary data with SQLite and Rails migrations may be touchy.

Comment: I think the real problem is that SQLite has very limited support for schema changes so you end up having to copy tables around. That combined with Rails not wanting to do the copying in straight SQL is probably where the problem arises.